# How does Linux handle 2 identical destinations in its routing table?

Tags: linux, routing, iproute

I have this is my routing table (in that order):

```
10.3.68.0/22 via 172.16.100.9 dev vlan4
10.3.68.0/22 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.3.69.254
```

`eth3` has ip `10.3.69.254/22`.

Why does Linux choose to go through the `172.16.100.9` gateway to access the `10.3.68.0/22` subnet (thus not trying direct link)?

I tested with `ip route get 10.3.68.123` for example. It says it will go through `172.16.100.9`, and in practice, it does.

It only says that it will try the link local routing when I ask for `10.3.68.0` ("network" address), `10.3.71.254` (broadcast), or `10.3.69.254` (itself). I think this is because these 3 cases are specifically handled by the higher priority `local` table (`ip route show table local`).

Anyway, **why does Linux consider the first route as the higher priority route?**

Comment: In the order of your routing table from the more to the less precise

Comment: @Kiwy can you source that information please?

Comment: Sorry I can't I'd rather delete my answer I don't even understand why I wrote this. The thing is for real routing table is processed from the more specific to the more broad but with vlan i really don't know

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a Vlan is more specific than a whole interface that's why it appears first in your routing table.
Thought I've not yet found documentation on it. I will update my answer if I find materials.

Answer (score 0):

I think no metrics are set, which means that the first entry is prioritized. You could set a metric for each entry. Then the entry with the lowest metric will be preferred. Do that using:

`sudo ip route del 10.3.68.0/22 via 172.16.100.9 dev vlan4`

`sudo ip route add 10.3.68.0/22 via 172.16.100.9 dev vlan4 metric 200`

`sudo ip route change 10.3.68.0/22 dev eth3 proto kernel scope link src 10.3.69.254 metric 100`

That should fix it.

Comment: I could see that in the question, there was no metric attribute.